# Restlet not closing InputRepresentation streams?

Tags: restlet

I'm very new to Reslet and I've come across a problem trying to stream data from a database blob using an InputRepresentation. Everything works fine when the blob is relatively small (10s of Kb) but when it's larger (say 500Kb) then I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException`s thrown.
 The data does eventually get transferred to the browser after many minutes, but much, much slower than it should take.

I am using Chrome and as far as I can tell it is making a GET request to the resource, then cancelling the request and making two further ranged requests, the first for bytes 0-32767 and the second for the remaining bytes. I think the problem arises because the after the first cancelled GET the server is not closing the InputPrepresentation stream, as mentioned here ["InputStream In not closing properly in InputRepresentation ..."](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/307) but I'm not familiar enough with the framework to be sure. I'm using version 2.1.7 and running inside Tomcat.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest 2.2.0 version (new stable branch) and try again? We have changed the default HTTP connector (part of org.restlet.jar) and that might solve your issue

Comment: It didn't appear to make any difference, as soon as I have a moment I'll double check.

Comment: Have you tried to call the release() method on your InputRepresentation instances?