# InputStream causing memory leaks

Tags: java, entity, inputstream, restlet

I'm using Restlet Framework but my question is more general Java question  on Streams. I have this code that returns a "blob" data / file on GET HTTP request:

```
@Override
public Representation getBlob() {
   InputStream is = entityRepository.getEntityBlob(appId, namespace, entityType, entityId, blobName);
   Representation representation = new InputRepresentation(is);
   representation.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
   representation.setSize(count);
   return representation;
}
```

I am also using k6.io load testing to test this resource, tested this for 1000 active connections for 10 mins and it did not have any issue, but this same machine and resource when tested for more time, hours for example, it then turns it starts eating all the memory of the machine causing it to halt eventually.

There seems to be a "leak" here but I cannot pinpoint as there is really no error at all.

**Update:**

This is how it looks:

```
public class BlobHashServerResource extends BaseServerResource implements BlobHashResource {
   @Override
   public Representation getBlob() { 
      //... 
   }
}
```

This `BlobHashServerResource` maps to

```
public class BackendApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
     router.attach("blobs/{blobHash}", BlobHashServerResource.class);
     return router; 
  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.mycompany.BackendApplication </param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: Is it possible for the `getBlob` method to return without any error, but for the *caller* of the `getBlob` method to throw some `Exception` and leave the returned `Representation` without invoking the [`release`](https://javadocs.restlet.talend.com/2.4/jse/api/org/restlet/representation/InputRepresentation.html#release--) method?

Comment: Or, can you please post the code that invokes the `getBlob` method? If I guess correctly the `getBlob` method does not serve requests directly, but is some kind of *service* method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @DenisZavedeev I have updated the post with code details

Comment: Also, which version of the restlet are you using? Probably, the version you are using has a bug and you need to upgrade, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658056/restlet-not-closing-inputrepresentation-streams) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to update Restlet Framework version, as this is a known InputStream issue/bug for older Restlet version, however some Restlet packages don't have the `2.4.0` version so I also indicated here the tested compatible version:

```
    <properties>
       <version.restlet>2.4.0</version.restlet>
    </properties>
   
    <dependencies>
       <!-- Restlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.raml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>raml-parser</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xstream</artifactId>
            <!--version>${version.restlet}</version-->
            <version>2.3.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.apispark</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.raml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>raml-parser</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
            <version>${version.restlet}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```